# Python module Cupy function gives error when using cupy.einsum()

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I am dealing with a problem with Cupy. I am currently using Cupy and it works great at a very satisfactory high speed. But I have a problem when I use `cupy.einsum()` method
I am using the same syntax with Numpy without any error. But when using Cupy it gives me an error. Here is the code section

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randn(2,3,10)
B = np.random.randn(3,4)
C = np.einsum('ijk,jl->ijl',A,B)
```

This works quite well and I get the result that I want consistently. However, when I write the same code with Cupy

```
import cupy as cp
A = cp.random.randn(2,3,10)
B = cp.random.randn(3,4)
C = cp.einsum('ijk,jl->ijl',A,B)
```

When I run this, A and B are calculated. But It gives me an error when calculating C. This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 4, in 
> C = cp.einsum('ijk,jl->ijl',A,B)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Okan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cupy\linalg\einsum.py",
> line 389, in einsum
> result_dtype = cupy.result_type(*operands) if dtype is None else dtype
>
> File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in result_type
>
> TypeError: no implementation found for 'numpy.result_type' on types
> that implement **array_function**: [<class 'cupy.core.core.ndarray'>]

I would be so glad if you have an idea or solution about this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: What NumPy/CuPy version are you using? Your NumPy code raises an error in my environment (`ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string contains too many subscripts for operand 0`) with NumPy 1.16.6 or 1.19.1.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I made a mistake when writing the code section. Not I have edited and the code section is running on my computer. But I still have the same issue about Cupy.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error with CuPy v7.8.0. Could you show what version are you using?

Comment: Right now, I am using anaconda, and apparently, it supports the version 6.0.0. https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cupy

Comment: That package seems out-dated (sorry for the confusion... we will discuss if it's better to remove it.) Could you use conda-forge packages for installing the latest CuPy? https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html#install-cupy-from-conda-forge

Answer (score 0):

For those who are experiencing the same problem, open a new environment in Conda and install the python version above 3.9. After that, when you install cupy by

```
conda install cupy
```

it will directly install the latest version (v.7.8 or higher). The problem was based on the version of the cupy. After upgarding, the problem fixed.